# Unable to open pull request from fork

Tags: git, github

I'm using Github to work on a project with a collaborator and we each have our own version of the project: I created mine by forking his. Several weeks ago, I finished with a set of changes, merged that branch with my master, and opened a pull request with my collaborator's master branch, which he accepted.

Today, I finished another set of changes, merged the branch with them into my master, and am unable to open a pull request with my collaborator's master branch. We can't figure out why.

Since I created the fork, he's made several changes, which I've merged into my fork by adding his repository as a remote and pulling from that. The project started as private and both of us recently made our branches public.

Does anyone have any idea why I cannot open a pull request? I think it might have something to do with the fact that he had already merged a pull request from my master branch, and Github wants me to open pull requests from different branches instead of from my master, but it seems strange to me that I can't find any way to open a pull request.

We were also thinking I could just create a new fork and copy over my commit history, if nothing else works.

To clarify what I mean by I'm unable to open a pull request, I've attached some screenshots. From each version of the project, I can't find the other fork. It's as if the two were completely separate projects and not forks of each other. In both screen shots, notice how it says there are 0 forks, even though mine was created from his.

[image]

From my fork, I can't select my collaborator's as the base fork (or as the head fork, for that matter).

[image]

From his, I can't select mine as the head fork (or as the base fork, for that matter).

Comment: Information on why it says you cannot create a pull request would be useful. Exactly what does it say or look like that makes it evident you cannot open a pull request? On Github, if you're looking at your repository on your master branch, what does it say right below the branch selector? For example, if the two repository master branches are equal, it will say `This branch is even with remote:master`.

Comment: From each of the versions, I can't even see the other fork: it's as if they were separate projects entirely. I've added a screenshot to my original question to show what I mean.

Comment: Has one of the repositories been deleted and recreated in the meantime (on GitHub, not local repositories)? If not, this may hint at an inconsistency at GitHub’s end. Maybe the support is able to “reconnect” them.

Comment: Neither of them have been deleted or recreated. I'll go ahead and reach out to GitHub support to see if they know what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reaching out to GitHub support, like Koraktor suggested, they pointed me to [this page](https://help.github.com/articles/making-a-private-repository-public/), which clarifies that making a private repository public will detachany private forks. So that's what happened to us. Unfortunately, they couldn't reattach the two, but I can create a new fork and push all my existing changes to it.